# C# winforms applications installed on server, managing common settings

Tags: c#, application-settings

we have a suite of applications which are add-ons to an enterprise product installed onto a windows server into the program files(x86) folder.  The applications are written in c#.  A share is created on the server allowing users to launch the applications in the installation folder either by terminal server or across the network.

The common settings for our applications are stored within a single xml file.  Some of these settings only need to be read and are configured by a dedicated application that requires admin rights (as it also performs other functions such as scheduling tasks).  Other settings need to be modified by various department managers to suit they way they want the applications to work and should not require admin access - but they need to be persisted in the same file as they are application rather than user specific.

I am somewhat confused with all of the available options for where the settings file might be stored (including special folders) such that admin access is not required to write to the file, yet the file location is accessible irrespective of whether the user is launching the application via terminal server, network share etc.

Is the program files folder the best option and just creating the necessary permissions on the share?  Or is there a special folder for this scenario?  If there is a special folder, what is the correct way to access it?  (I did try this route, but kept finding the file was being created/updated on the user's local machine rather than the network file).

thanks

Matt

Comment: Are the programs you're talking about all programs that your company has produced, and that you can modify so that they can handle whatever policy you decide on for settings files? Or are they programs that are closed to you, or that you can't modify for some other reason?

Comment: "Is the program files folder the best option ..." In general I would not recommend that technique.

Comment: "deployment" to network share is *not* recommended.  You should either install the application on each workstation, or deploy via ClickOnce.

Comment: The products are add-ons to an existing application which is installed as a network shared application.

Comment: I like the idea of ClickOnce Sam, but it's not really an option at this point in time (and may never be).  The focus and preference at the moment is to handle common, global settings changed by managers ideally all captured in a single file (rather than split across different repositories) as it simplifies design, support training and porting to another machine.